# Why is there an err argument required for Scanln, and when i assign a variable to it, I cannot transfer it to byte data in the function WriteFile>?

Tags: go

Why is there is a required error `err` variable for the `fmt.Scanln` function?
I also need help understanding the purpose of the `fmt.Writeln` parameters.

The purpose of this program is to get input data from the user by the command line and output it to a file `go-log.go`

```golang
package main

import ("fmt"
        "os")

func main() {

  YNQ := "yes"

  for YNQ == "yes" {

    fmt.Println("What do you want to add to the log?")

    openfile, err := os.Open("go-log.txt")

    addedText, err := fmt.Scanln()

    os.WriteFile("go-log.txt", []byte(addedText), 0666)

    //add date and time here

    fmt.Println("Would you like to add anything else?")

    fmt.Scanln(&YNQ)
  }
  openfile.Close()
}
  
 - errors recieved:
   
       -cannot convert addedText (type int) to type [byte]
       -undefined: openfile
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/fmt-scanln-function-in-golang-with-examples/amp/

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's make your code readable with the `go fmt` command:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    YNQ := "yes"
    for YNQ == "yes" {
        fmt.Println("What do you want to add to the log?")
        openfile, err := os.Open("go-log.txt")
        addedText, err := fmt.Scanln()
        os.WriteFile("go-log.txt", []byte(addedText), 0666)
        //add date and time here
        fmt.Println("Would you like to add anything else?")
        fmt.Scanln(&YNQ)
    }
    openfile.Close()
}
```

Second, let's try to understand and answer your questions. You are asking:

> Why is there is a required error `err` variable for the `fmt.Scanln` function?

1. Go compiler forces you to assign either all return values to variables or none of them. You can also use a placeholder `_` marking that you are not interested in this variable. Please, read this article for more information: https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values.
2. Scanln returns the error because there might be an error when you scan a standard output.

> I also need help understanding the purpose of the `fmt.Writeln` parameters.

There is no function `Writeln` in the package `fmt`: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#pkg-index

> `cannot convert addedText (type int) to type [byte]`

Please, carefully read the documentation for the `fmt.Scanln` function: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanln. It does not return text. It writes what it reads from the `stdin` to its arguments. These arguments are supposed to be pointers to variables you want to populate: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fmt-scanln-function-in-golang-with-examples/

> `undefined: openfile`

The `openfile` variable is indeed not available in this scope. Please, read this article about scopes in Go: https://medium.com/golangspec/scopes-in-go-a6042bb4298c

> The purpose of this program is to get input data from the user by the command line and output it to a file go-log.go

The program should look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("go-log.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    YNQ := "yes"
    for YNQ == "yes" {
        fmt.Println("What do you want to add to the log?")
        
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        var line string
        if scanner.Scan() {
            line = scanner.Text()
        } else {
            log.Fatalln("Cannot read from stdin.")
        }
        
        if _, err = f.WriteString(line + "\n"); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        
        fmt.Println("Would you like to add anything else?")
        _, err := fmt.Scanln(&YNQ)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See its documentation: [`Scanln`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanln)

The doc refers to [`Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scan) and this explains what the functions return ("the number of items") and why they would error:

"It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is less than the number"